# wcf data service $filter to search between datetimes

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, datetime, service

I'm working on a project to get data from a database and output it into and xml on a webpage (api) . Now that all works but i want to query my data between to datetimes and i have no clue how to do this :( . can anybody help me ? This is the url i thought it was but it isn't

if anybody could help me it would help me that would be amazing

```
$filter=ModifiedDate gt datetime'2012-05-02T00:00:00' and lt datetime'2013-05-02T00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Between` for selecting some data between two dates.

example:

```
Select * from Table where Datecolumn BETWEEN //value1 AND //value2
```